# Error when trying to deallocate binary search tree (only with primitive data types)

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a BST which performs common operations, Insertion, Deletion, Search, and traversals.

The problem I have found is that the created tree works perfectly when it is assigned to use **non-primitive data types**, For exmple: user defined struct, classes and C++ stl classes (as `std::string`)

But when I use `int`, `double_t`, `int64_t` and so, it throws an exception.

```cpp
    ~BinaryNode()
    {
        if (left_ != NULL)
            Deleting(left_);
        if (right_ != NULL)
            Deleting(right_);
        //The exception occurs here when the primitive data type
        //is attempted to be deallocated
    }

    //Using preorder to delete this tree recursively
    void Deleting(BinaryNode<T> *node)
    {
        if (node == NULL) return;
        if (node->left_ != NULL)
            delete node->left_;
        if (node->right_ != NULL)
            delete node->right_;
        node->left_ = node->right_ = NULL;
        delete node;
    }
```

I had made many tests, checking the integrity between nodes and that's not the problem. Because, As I said, the problem is when the destructor reaches its end.

When I used the debugger I saw that a `std::string` calls its destructor and is correctly deallocated. But with primitive types it throws an exception of type:

```
Exception has occurred.
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Thanks Beforehand.

#### Edit:

I am testing it as:

```
int main()
{
    BinarySearchTree<uint64_t> bst(
        [](const uint64_t &t1, const uint64_t &t2) -> int8_t {
            if (t1 == t2) return 0;
            if (t1 > t2) return 1;
            else return -1;
        });

    //performance slow down because there are (20000^2)/2 operations
    //to do. This is not a Self Balanced tree, so it is expected
    //it ends having worst performance than a singly linked list
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
    // i <= 20000 causes error
    // i <= 200 or i <= 2000 works perfect
    {
        bst.Insert(i);
        std::cout << "i:" << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << bst.Size() << std::endl;
    bst.Clear();//this generates the error. [When i <= 20000]
}
```

Definition of Insert

```cpp
    virtual bool Insert(const T &t)
    {
        if (this->root_ == NULL)
        {
            this->root_ = new BinaryNode<T>(t);
            return true;
        }
        return Insert(t, this->root_);
    }

    virtual bool Insert(const T& t, BinaryNode<T> *node)
    {
        if (this->comparing_(t, node->t_) > 0)
            if (node->left_ == NULL)
            {
                node->left_ = new BinaryNode<T>(t);
                this->size_++;
            }
            else Insert(t, node->left_);
        else if (this->comparing_(t, node->t_) < 0)
            if (node->right_ == NULL)
            {
                node->right_ = new BinaryNode<T>(t);
                this->size_++;
            }
            else Insert(t, node->right_);
        else return false; //if there is such element
        return true; //if it was successfully inserted
    }
```

This is the definition of Clear

```cpp
    virtual void Clear()
    {
        delete root_;
        root_ = NULL;
    }
```

Note: `comparing_` is a lambda.

**I think that this is a recursion error.**

Comment: Note: I will use `std::unique_ptr` to check if it works

Comment: Don't use NULL in C++. Use nullptr.

Comment: Not enough code to see the issue. And also, post more debugger info.

Comment: Except for the first null check in `Deleting` where you do a return, you don't need any of those null pointer checks in your code.  Deleting a nullptr is perfectly ok, and your function `Deleting` already returns if the node is null.  At least half the code you posted would just go away.

Comment: post all your code, i think your problem is not comming from `Deleting` function

Comment: You don't need all this complicated deletion code. It accomplishes nothing. You just need `~BinaryNode() { delete left_ ; delete right_ ; }`. You also don't need a separate node class. Every node is a tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error was produced due to a stack overflow error. Why? Because the stack of calls was adding as many calls as nodes were at an unbalanced side of the tree.

Due the nature of an unbalanced binary search tree this happens, there is a limit for recursion. I tried adding 20.000 and 200.000 elements into a AVLTree and it worked fine due the self balancing procedure, because it ensures the tree to have a height O(ln(n))

Answer (score -1):

As I can't see the node class so according to my understanding:
The data types like **int** can't be assigned NULL.

Comment: There are no assignments in this code at all, let alone assignments to NULL.